# How to increase max heap size

Tags: java, out-of-memory, weka, heap-memory

Refer to the screenshot below:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Hint: you only use screen shots as very last resort. And you **never** put up links to external sites. If you really have to, put the screen shot INTO your question.

Comment: Use a system with more RAM? This might be a physical limitation.

Comment: Run your program with the flag :  -Xmx   i.e   -Xmx1024M -->1GB Max Heap size   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565388/increase-heap-size-in-java

Comment: @firephil It's already using 2.1 Gb with a limit of 2.6 Gb, so you're suggesting that *lowering* that limit to 1 Gb would help?

Comment: @Andreas The screenshot is not clear, i suggested to use the flag not a specific number.

Comment: This is a WEKA FAQ.  See [WEKA FAQ](https://weka.wikispaces.com/Frequently+Asked+Questions)